# flash app to create txt file on your drive (without installing ofline server)

Tags: flash, text, input, save, local

I've been struggling with this one for a few days now (but that's only because I'm stranger to scripting) so I would rly appreciate if anyone could guide me or even better send me a rough template on this:

A little app consisting of 6 lines. On each line should be 2 TextInput boxes and one DropBox with multiple values (value1, value2, value3 ...)
And there would be a button that would gather data from all lines and saved them on local drive as .txt file in following format:

```
Line1 = [1,"abc123","abc123"]
line2 = [7,"abc123","abc123"]
...
```

If nothing is filled than it would be saved as

```
line1 = [,"",""]
...
```

The first number (in my example 1 and 7) is result of chosen value in DropBox on each line. And content of quotation marks can be anything written in those text InputBoxes on each line.

This problem has been driving me crazy for a few days now. I rely hope someone can help me.
BTW Ive found a topic that probably answers to part of my problem http://www.flash.cz/portal/clanek.aspx?id=1191 , but wasn't able to make it work.. I rely need someone holding my hand in the world of scripting :(

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.events.Event;

ulozit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,SaveFile);
function getData():Array
{
    var zoznam:Array = [];
    var seznam:Array = [pocasi1,pocasi2,pocasi3];
    var seznamnoc:Array = [pocasinoc1,pocasinoc2,pocasinoc3];
    var s:String = "";
    for(var i = 1;i < 13;i++)
    {
        s = "";
        s = "radek"+i +" = [" + seznam[i - 1].selectedItem.data + "," + seznamnoc[i - 1].selectedItem.data + ",";
        if(this["den" + i].length > 0)s += '"' + this["den" + i].text + '"' + ",";
        else s+= '"",';
        if(this["noc" + i].length > 0)s += '"' + this["noc" + i].text +'"';
        else s+= '""';
        s += "]";
        zoznam.push(s);
    }
    return zoznam;
}
function SaveFile(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var s:String = "";
    var arrs:Array = getData();
    for(var i = 0;i < arrs.length;i++)s += arrs[i] + " " +"\n" + "\n";
    var f:FileReference = new FileReference();
    f.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onSaveFileComplete);
    f.save(s,"pocasi.txt");
}
function onSaveFileComplete(e:Event):void
{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onSaveFileComplete);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question ... Not using AIR or Zinc but running from the browser without installing your code, the only way I know of to save a file to a user's hard drive is to prompt the user where they would like to save the file. For security reasons the user must accept to save it. To accomplish this you can consider using [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29), something like:

```
import flash.net.FileReference;

function promptUserToSaveTextFile(fileContent:String)
{
    var ref:FileReference = new FileReference();
    ref.save(fileContent, 'someDefaultFileName.txt');
}

promptUserToSaveTextFile("contents of the file all in one string");
```

**But wait ... a Shared Object may be what you want**

Looking at the big picture of what you are trying to accomplish, if you are wanting to automatically save some data to the user's local computer to reference later, look into [SharedObjects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html). I think of them like cookies but for Flash. This is by far better than prompting the end user to save a text file in possibly some random location and file name that they can change.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I want this to be happening offline. So AIR would deffinately be the way.. If only I understood scripting. I got stucked on as2.0 and even that I can use just for animation controll.. Could you tell me how to do it via Flash AIR project? And please, please go with me thru the one whole line of the application, including the event thatwould start it and make the save button active. Otherwise Im very likely to keep on strugling like after I found that link I posted. I think thats solution for the InputText part, just dunno how to use it. Thanks again.